# PING php deixando retorno da página lenta?

Tags: php

Estou montando um sistema de monitoramento e algumas outras funçoes, dentre eles estou criando um Dashboard que me da o retorno do equipamento "ON" ou "OFF" por ping com o seguinte código;

```
<?php
        $host="10.41.5.9";
        exec("ping -c 4 " . $host, $output, $result);
        if ($result == 0)
        {

        ?>
        <div class="w3-quarter">
          <div class="w3-container w3-green w3-padding-16" id="class_ping">
            <div class="w3-left"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o w3-xxxlarge"></i></div>
            <div class="w3-right">
             <h5>UNIDADE CEARÁ</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-clear"></div>

            <h6>Impressora Atual</h6>
            <span><strong><?php echo $impressora1;?></strong></span><br>
            <i class='fa fa-gear fa-spin'></i> - Impressora ONLINE
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }else{
        echo  "";
        ?>
        <div class="w3-quarter">
          <div class="w3-container w3-red w3-padding-16" id="class_ping">
            <div class="w3-left"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o w3-xxxlarge"></i></div>
            <div class="w3-right">
              <h5>UNIDADE CEARÁ</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-clear"></div>

            <h6>Impressora Atual</h6>
            <span><strong><?php echo $impressora1;?></strong></span><br>
            <i class='fa fa-gear'></i> - Impressora OFFLINE
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

A questão em sí, eu gostaria de saber se existe como deixar o ip para pingar após o carregamento da página, para ele testar o ping após a página ja ter dado o load !
Obrigado.

Comment: Mas se você precisa do resultado para exibir a página, como ele seria executado depois?

Comment: Então, esse ping é o retorno de uma impressora, ele é executando para exibir no dash dessa página, o que está acontecendo agora é que a página está demorando a ser carregada pois ele está fazendo o teste de ping, o que eu gostaria de saber se é possível é, carregar a pagina e depois de carregada ele executar o ping.

Comment: Pode trazer o retorno do ping a partir de uma requisição AJAX; o que acha?

Comment: É uma boa, porém não estou muito familiarizado com AJAX, entrei no mundo php a pouco tempo heheh, nao sei aplicar isso ainda , mas vou dar uma estudada pra ver como posso aplicar isso no meu código. Tem algum exemplo pra ver como se faz ?

Comment: o PHP trabalha por execução, então não tem como você fazer isso que você quer. Se você quer carregar a página antes de executar o ping, sugiro AJAX como o @AndersonCarlosWoss sugeriu

Comment: Show cHida, depois desse post me obriguei a estudar mais afundo ajax/Jquery pela necessidade que venho tendo nos meus desenvolvimentos na empresa. Obrigado pela ajuda !!!